# OnClicklisteners and Message box Issues?

Tags: android

Hmm.. I am getting an errors saying the constructor is undefined.

```
Dele.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View arg0) {



    EditText DelSel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETDeleteSelect);

                   int Id = Integer.parseInt(DelSel.getText().toString());

                   builder = new ***AlertDialog.Builder(this);***
                   builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                          .setCancelable(false)
                          .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   MyActivity.this.finish();
                              }
                          })
                          .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
```

can someone tell me whats the fix? i get an error called

"The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined"

What i am trying to do is open a message box when a button is clicked where to continue or not. so someone please help me out.

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder()` takes one parameter and that `Context` of a `Activity` where your `AlertDialog` is to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `this` with :

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
```

The `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor expects a `Context` reference and right now you giving it a `OnClickeListener` reference(because you're using `this` in the anonymous `OnClickListener` class that you declare as your listener).

Comment: Thanks. :D I used the Same Technique. :D

Comment: @ShivaBala As an advice, **never** use the method `getApplicationContext()`(this method returns a `Context` and you could be tempted to use it to instantiate the dialog) to instantiate an `AlertDialog`.